# Как переопределить бутерброд-меню в bootstrap под другое разрешение?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

В меню сделанном на `bootstrap` и меня много пунктов меню и при определенном разрешении экрана, они сползают на 2оу строчку - [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/kcpma/801/). Как сделать так, чтобы сворачивание в бутерброд происходило прежде, чем пункты меню окажутся на другой строчке? По умолчанию сворачивание происходит только при `768px`

```css
.navbar-brand {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar > .container > * {
    display: table-cell !important;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/66x61">Bootstrap 3 Skeleton
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Navbar Links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">First</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">Second</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">Third</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">Forth</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используете LESS/SASS версию бутстрапа - увеличьте значение переменной `@grid-float-breakpoint`.

Если используете CSS версию - проставьте нужное вам значение [в форме на сайте бутстрапа](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) и сгенерируйте себе индивидуальную CSS-сборку, которую подключите вместо стандартной.